# Does employment make a difference when applying for a visitor visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a 25-year-old woman and I have a job where I have been working only for 7 month with 380 euro salary. Now that I am applying for a Schengen visa, I am concerned that my mom's schengen visa application was refused once and it might influence my visa application. Does that make a difference in applying for a visitor visa? It's my first time applying for Schengen visa.

Comment: Visitor visa to where? It's a big world and this question is extremely broad. In general, yes, having a job is better than not having a job when you're applying for a visitor visa, because it gives one reason you would need to return home on time. But there are many factors, and nobody here can predict whether you'll get a visa or not. The only way to find out is to apply.

Comment: As opposed to what? Being unemployed, disabled and unable to work, retired, a seasonal employee and laid off during the off-season...?

Comment: Yes it surely makes a difference

Comment: Your other question is *on hold*. You are asking very general questions, which are difficult to answer for that reason. Read this answer regarding finances: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105

Comment: schengen visa, been working only 7 month, 380 euro salary but my mom's visa was refused once

Comment: @Lisa Hi, please edit your information into the question. The new information may be enough to have people vote to reopen, or it may end up being a duplicate question. In addition, your country of citizenship, whether you've traveled in Schengen and/or gotten any other "first world" visas in the past will also be useful.

Comment: To answer the initial question: Yes, employment makes a whole lot of difference and might actually be the most important factor in the decision.

Answer (score 1):

Employment does make a difference - most countries don't want to issue visas to people without a stable source of income. On the other hand earning only 380 euros per month could be interpreted as too little for someone to be able to afford a trip to the Schengen area, depending on where in the world you are located.

My advice would be to save up enough money to cover flights, accommodation and other expenses, and then apply for a visa with a 6-month bank statement and a proof of employment.